# Call Java Enum method from JNI

Tags: java, android, enums, java-native-interface

I have a scenario where I need to call enum method in native code. This enum is defined in Java.

```
public enum Pool {
    JNIPOOL(new SomePoolStrategyImp()),
    UIPOOL(new RandomPoolStrategyImp());

    private PoolStrategy poolStrategy;

    Pool(PoolStrategy poolStrategy) {
        this.poolStrategy = poolStrategy;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(int width, int height) {
        // some logic
        // return poolStrategy.getBitmap(width, height);
    }
}
```

I have references where object methods can be called from JNI but in my case, I need to call already created object method. Like I need to call `JNIPOOL.getBitmap()` from native code. Can anyone help me with this? I just want to the approach or any existing blog which can help me in this.

Thanks!

Comment: An enum constant is just a field. Get the class `Pool`, get the field `JNIPOOL`, read it's value`, call `getBitmap` with the value.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Please see updated description. I have some custom logic behind JNIPOOL which differs from other pools. And I want JNIPOOL logic to be trigerred in native call.

Comment: Does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already told, an enum constant is just a field.

To test my solution, I used a native method with the following signature:

```
private static native Bitmap callBitmap(int width, int height);
```

in the class `test.JNITest`. This is the native code in C++:

```c++
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_test_JNITest_callBitmap
(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jint width, jint height) {
    // Get a reference to the class
    jclass poolc = env->FindClass("test/Pool");
    // get the field JNIPOOL
    jfieldID jnipoolFID = env->GetStaticFieldID(poolc, "JNIPOOL", "Ltest/Pool;");
    jobject jnipool = env->GetStaticObjectField(poolc, jnipoolFID);

    // Find the method "getBitmap", taking 2 ints, returning test.Bitmap
    jmethodID getBitmapMID = env->GetMethodID(poolc, "getBitmap", "(II)Ltest/Bitmap;");

    // Call the method.
    jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(jnipool, getBitmapMID, width, height);

    return result;
}
```